# send mail by zapier using mailchimp

Tags: ajax, mailchimp, zapier

I want to send mail using zapier with mailchimp.

What I did:

In my webiste I put ajax request and add zapier webhook.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/xzyabc/", // this is zapier webhook
    type: "POST", 
    data: zapierData,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log('Zapier Success: ', result);
    },
    errors: function(error) {
      console.log('Zapier Error:', error);
        }
});
```

What else I need to do please explain step by step if anybody knows ?

Thanks,

Comment: are you getting an error? are there any logs? it's not clear from your question why the above isn't working

Comment: I want to send mail from my website using MailChimp via Zapier. Lets suppose:
I have form in my website, once customer fill form I want to trigger mail using MailChimp Via Zapier. Hope you my question now. but in success I am not getting any error. Even also mail is not triggering.

Comment: can you post one of the success responses? it should have data like `fork` and `attempt`, which will help us track it down

Comment: Below is object I am getting in success: {attempt: "5d3b3df7-4f52-4426-aba4-496d83241f20"
id: "ad151838-d9b8-49d4-8c0d-68b1737db4a2"
request_id: "5d3b3df7-4f52-4426-aba4-496d83241f20"
status: "success"}
Actually, If I choose option to add/update subscribe then it is working fine, but I want to send mail like every time use fill form, the mail should trigger. If possible for you can we talk on skype: anks.kumar066.

Comment: do you see error items in the task history? zapier is receiving the hook, but it looks like mailchimp is throwing an error